# How do I get my look up table values in a select box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lookup-tables

Reading along with the agile book, it says this in a footnote:

> ... You simply pass the select helper the result of doing a ﬁnd(:all) on your lookup 
>   table.

Okay ...

```
<%= f.select :source, Source.find(:all) %>
```

My source controller (and therefore table) looks like this:

```
create_table :sources do |t|
  t.string :source

  t.timestamps
end
```

But my select box is a mess, I get this type of data in all the values and displays:

```
#<Source:0x23a2bfc>
```

So I tried doing a `Source.find(:all, :select => 'name,id')` but that still gives me the whacky looking stuff.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Source.find(:all)
```

will return an array of Source objects - this is not what you want.  What you wants is an array of options.  Something *like*:

```
select(:source, "source_id", Source.all.collect {|p| [ p.source, p.id ] })
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly. I knew there was something I had to do like this ... what's the difference between .collect and .map?

Comment: There is no difference. `map` is an alias for `collect`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass a collection of options (or key-value options). The third parameter in `select` is actually passed to the `options_for_select` method. This is best illustrated with an example.

```
options_for_select(["a", "b"])
```

... becomes

```
<option>a</option><option>b</option>
```

Most of the time you'll be more interested in key-value pairs

```
options_for_select([["a", "1"], ["b", "2"]])
```

... becomes

```
<option value="1">a</option><option value="2">b</option>
```

As a short-hand, it's common to pass an entire collection of objects and map them to conform what `options_for_select` is expecting.

```
options_for_select(Model.all.map { |m| [m.attr1, m.attr2] })
```

...and to answer your question using the `select` method inside of a view

```
<%= f.select(:method, Model.all.map { |m| [m.attr1, m.attr2] }) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I'd have marked both as answers if I could since they do the same thing.